# How to force maven to always download parent pom

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am using a parent pom to share dependencies and plugins across multiple projects.  The parent pom is deployed to our nexus repository.  In child project, parent pom is included like this:

```
<project>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>app-web</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-internal-site</id>
      <url>http://nexus/repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

When parent pom gets updated, would like to keep the same version so child project automatically gets the updated dependencies without updates.  However, it seems parent pom is not updated even if I use 
`mvn clean -U`

How do I force maven (maven 3) to always download parent pom from remote repo even if it is already in local repository?

Comment: You probably want your parent pom to be at a SNAPSHOT version to get the behaviour you want. Otherwise, if you are updating the parent pom, you should be updating the version.

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined such parent which is a release it will be downloaded exactly once. Afterwards it will not downloaded a second time cause release are imutable. As already mentioned you mind need to think about using SNAPSHOT's instead.

Answer (score 0):

you should re-install parent project into your local repo, try run `mvn install` under app-parent directory!

Comment: Thanks, this would be an option but I would like to download the parent from remote repository, not local repo.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I had a case where maven was not downloading a parent but just a .lastUpdated file (which listed a download failure).  Even if I ran help:effective-pom it seem to just ignore the fact the parent was undownloadable and absent, and continue on its merry way.

Fix was to upgrade from maven 3.3.3 to 3.3.9